# SwiftUI: How to make a transparent Rectangle (.fill(.clear)) receive gestures?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to overlay my image with several `Rectangle()`s, that should respond to gestures (like tapping or dragging). However, I found that when I make the rectangle clear, it stops receiving gestures.

```swift
Rectangle()
  .fill(.clear)
  .gesture(
    LongPressGesture()
      .onEnded { value in 
        // this isn't called when the rectangle fill is .clear
      }
  )
```

Is there a way to let an invisible element receive taps? I know that I could give it a 1 % opacity, but that feels like an ugly (and visible) kludge.

Comment: I don't know if it's good to ask, but why not just put .gesture on your image instead? it's more reasonable and you don't have to work with extra rectangles.

Comment: @tail This is a simplified example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add content shape that defines hit-testable area, like

```
Rectangle()
  .fill(.clear)
  .contentShape(Rectangle())   // << here !!
  .gesture(
```

Answer (score 2):

One extra way apart from @Asperi's answer is

```swift
Color.clear.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: It is obvious, but does not correspond to a question, which is about Rectangle, just in case.

Comment: @Asperi Don't worry, I accepted your answer (thank you!), but the core of the question was 'how to make a transparent area clickable' - by any means :)